# How to remove H tag from user register form in drupal for SEO purpose

Tags: users, theming

I want to remove  tag from user register form in drupal for SEO purpose.How can I achieve it in drupal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) to alter form field which you want to alter. The `$form_id` would be `user_register_form`.

```
function MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    // do the altering you want here
  }
}
```